# Immutable js map store object losing methods

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability, flux

Everything works fine until I run a method to add some objects to the store, that is triggering a re render on the view... The thing is in the first page load the store on the component is a map with all its methods, after update and when the component gets re rendered it loses the methods and is turned into a plain js object, obviously the component tries to do a store.get() for example and it fails :S

here it is an screenshot:

[image: a console log in the store and below a console log to the object on the react component]
and some code:

```
class BlogStore {
  constructor() {
    this.bindListeners({
      handleBlogs: Actions.UPDATE_BLOGS,
      handleBlogPost: Actions.UPDATE_BLOG_POST,
      addMoreBlogs: Actions.ADD_MORE_BLOGS,
    });

    console.log('STORE: state before initialization', this.store);
    /* here is where the state structure is defined */
    this.state = Immutable.Map({
      blogs: {
        blogList: [],
        meta: {
          count: 0,
        },
        currentPage: 1,
      },
      blogPost: []
    });
  }

  /* here is where the state gets modified */
  addMoreBlogs(blogs) {
    console.log('addMoreBlogs executed');
    console.log('STORE: state before convertion to js', this.state);
    console.log('we have to add this to the store', blogs);

    //const currentPage = this.state.blogs.currentPage + 1;

    console.log('STORE: blogList should not be empty', this.state.get('blogs').blogList.concat(blogs.blogList));

    const updatedBlogs = this.state.get('blogs').blogList.concat(blogs.blogList);
    const updatedMeta = this.state.get('blogs').meta;

    console.log('STORE: updatedBlogs', updatedBlogs);
    console.log('STORE, updatedMeta', updatedMeta);

    this.setState(this.state.setIn(
      ['blogs'],
      {
        blogList: updatedBlogs,
        meta: updatedMeta,
        currentPage: 1,
      }
      ));

      console.log('STORE: updated state', this.state);
  }
  ...
```

and the component:

```
class BlogsWrapper extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    /* get the store data and transform it to plain js */
    this.state = Store.getState();

    //console.log('BLOGSWRAPPER: state gotten in constructor:', this.state);
    this._onChange = this._onChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Store.listen(this._onChange);

    // if (this.state.get('blogs').isEmpty()) {
    //   this.context.router.push('/blog/not-found');
    //   return;
    // }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    Store.unlisten(this._onChange);

    //console.log('BLOGSWRAPPER: resetting page counter');
  }

  _onChange() {
    //this.setState(Store.getState().toJS());
    this.setState(Store.getState());
    console.log('BLOGSWRAPPER: onchange fired', this.state);
  }**

  ...
```

any help on this? I can't figure out what is going on, I tried also re create the store object on the addMoreBlogs method with the same result. Any help/suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue recently, I think you should use `mergeIn` instead of `setIn` if planning to modify state with an object.

Check this [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/gelukidame/edit?js,output) for the same explanation.

Comment: Nice approach, changing to mergeIn. Thanks! I think it fits better what I need to accomplish. But it does not resolve the main issue, the component stills receiving an Object instead of a Map

Comment: I think you need to change to fromJS instead of immutable.map in the constructor. That's what I did in the JSBin example

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
this.setState(this.state.setIn(
  ['blogs'],
  Immutable.formJS({
    blogList: updatedBlogs,
    meta: updatedMeta,
    currentPage: 1,
  })));
```

Obviously, this is a hack. When you work with immutable state, you should avoid updating all state in that manner. Instead, you need to update exact field of you Immutable object. That's why guys from Facebook recommend keeping state as flat as possible.

Comment: its an option but its good to use mergeIn for this type of cases. No need to use 2 APIs (`fromJS` and `SetIn`)